# Use older tensorflow 1.0 package inside current new project

Tags: migration, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow1.15

there are many questions already between migrating from Tensorflow (TF) 1.0 to TF 2.0. However, I would like to combine an old package (not written by me) and use their code to build something new. I do not have much experience writing TF code, so I don't want to refactor their code. To be specific, the package I want to use is the [data valuation using reinforcement learning](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/master/dvrl/dvrl.py).

How can I use this package inside my own code base, without needing to refactor everything?

So I have my own project, using TF 2.0, and I import (some) of their functions.